# Casting a long javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result to list of Strings is very slow

Tags: java, string, list

The for loop at the end of this is very slow when there are 50k rows.  Is there a quicker way to get a list of Strings from the rows of a **javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result**?  Use a different collection?  Convert the Strings differently?

The query is absolutely fine.  I am not including here the custom objects that are used to run it.  I can't change them.  I think you only need to know that it returns a Result.

(I didn't write any of this code.)

```
    private int m_ObjectGroupId;
    private int m_FetchSize;
    private ArrayList<String> m_InternalIds;
```

...method following member initialisation...

```
    String internalIdString = "INTERNALID";
    String selectSql = "SELECT " + internalIdString + " FROM MODELOBJECT WHERE OBJECTGROUPID = ?";

    ArrayList<Object> valuesToSet = new ArrayList<Object>();
    valuesToSet.add(m_ObjectGroupId);

    BaseForPreparedStatement selectStatement = new BaseForPreparedStatement(selectSql.toString(), valuesToSet);

    SqlQueryResult queryResult = DBUtils.executeQueryRS(p_Context, selectStatement, getConnection(), m_FetchSize);
    Result result = queryResult.getResult();
    m_InternalIds = new ArrayList<>(result.getRowCount());

    for (int i = 0; i < result.getRowCount(); i++) {
        m_InternalIds.add((String)result.getRows()[i].get(internalIdString));
    }
```

UPDATE:
The query only takes 1s whereas the loop takes 30s.
result.getRows().getClass() is a java.util.SortedMap[].

Comment: How long does the query itself take to return all rows? Are you sure it’s the loop that’s causing the slowness? It could be the collection type. What is the output of this: `System.out.println(result.getRows().getClass());`?

Comment: @Bohemian yes, the query only takes a second.  The for loop takes about 30 seconds.  I will check the class...

Comment: @Bohemian result.getRows().getClass() is a java.util.SortedMap[]

Comment: But does the query return *all rows* within a second, or does it return the *first* rows within a second?

Comment: The type of the row set seems OK - array access is O(1) and each SortedMap has only 1 entry so that’s  O(1), so the overall access is O(1).

Comment: @Bohemian if I have it in debug then it takes 1s to get from the query line to the for line.  Are you saying that the Result is still being built in the background?  On the for line after 1s, the result.getRowCount() is 50k.

Comment: OK. You have convinced me that the whole query takes only 1 second.

Comment: What are those `SqlQueryResult` and `Result` classes? What does `result.getRows()` do?

Comment: @ThomasKläger Result is a javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result.  result.getRows() is a java.util.SortedMap[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the implementation of `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result#getRows()` (for example the Tomcat taglibs at https://github.com/apache/tomcat-taglibs-standard/blob/main/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/sql/ResultImpl.java#L134) it can be that `getRows()` does unnecessary work each time you call it.

You could rewrite your extraction loop as

```
for (SortedMap m: result.getRows()) {
    m_InternalIds.add((String) m.get(internalIdString));
}
```

which calls `getRows()` only once.

Comment: OMG, it went down to less than a second.  Same amount of IDs added.  Thank you so much!